# How to center the boxes as shown?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/do4rdxgn/2/

HTML :

```
<div class = "semesters">

<a href="Semester2.html"> Semester 2</a>
<a href="Semester3.html"> Semester 3</a>
<a href="Semester4.html"> Semester 4</a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.semesters a {
    color:#D8DACF;
    background:black;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;   
}
```

As you can see, the black boxes along with the text are clumped up to the left of the page. I want to make these black boxes look something like this.

[image]

How do I do that? If I set padding equal a number the black boxes increase in size and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
.semesters {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}
.semesters a {
    color:#D8DACF;
    background:black;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/do4rdxgn/8/)

Comment: align='center' is deprecated.

Comment: That's better fo sho.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.btn {
     background: #000000;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #404040);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #404040);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #404040);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #404040);
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #404040);
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0px;
     font-family: Arial;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 23px;
     padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
     background: #292929;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #000000);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #000000);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #000000);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #000000);
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #292929, #000000);
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
    .semesters
    {
         text-align:center;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `<div>` into a `<table>`, give it `width: 100%`, and you're good to go!

```css
.semesters a {
 color:#D8DACF;
    background:black;
 font-size:30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
}
.semesters {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<table class="semesters"><tr>
<td><a href="Semester2.html"> Semester 2</a></td>
<td><a href="Semester3.html"> Semester 3</a></td>
<td><a href="Semester4.html"> Semester 4</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

`<table>`s automatically split up the `<td>`s equally across the width of the entire `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

you try margin as like this and set margin as screen width small screen reduce margin and big screen increase margin.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/swepmugo/)

```
.semesters{
text-align:center;
}
.semesters a {
color:#D8DACF;
background:black;
font-size:30px;
text-decoration: none;
display:inline;
padding:10px;   
margin:0 1.5%;
}
```